# How to make entire td a link?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I make this entire td a link?

```
<td id="blue-border"><span id="blue"></span></td>
```

Clicking td should make it behave like this (I know this is syntactically incorrect:

```
<a href="javascript:chooseStyle('blue-theme', 360)"> <td id="blue-border"><span id="blue"></span></td> </a>
```

EDIT: so far all the suggestions are only making the span inside the td a link, help lol.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why does the table cell have to be linkable?

Comment: It then acts like a giant button, which could be very mobile-friendly.

Comment: I concur with the OP - none of the solutions make the whole TD, including the TD's padding/margins, clickable!  The `onclick=` method might work, but nobody's yet provided a working example of making it hyperlink.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use CSS.

```css
td a { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Link</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The CSS forces the link to expand to the full width and height of the TD.

Comment: @LedZeppelin Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/upBDc/ ... there are any number of things that could be going wrong with your code.  Do you have a link?

Comment: This works when the td's height is explicitly specified, but not when it's determined by the other things in the row, apparently: http://jsfiddle.net/ypj10jyj/2/

Comment: This doesn't expand the `<a>` into the td's margins/padding - they are not clickable.

Comment: Naturally not.  Content doesn't expand into padding.  If you need the clickable region of the `<a>` to extend all the way to the edges, then you'll need to remove any padding on the `<td>`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't wrap a td in an anchor.  Do this:

```
<td id="blue-border"><a href="javascript:chooseStyle('green-theme', 360)"> <span id="blue"></span></a></td>
```

Or

```
<td onclick="chooseStyle('green-theme', 360)" id="blue-border"><span id="blue"></span></td>
```

Comment: What would the syntax be for making the <td> hyperlink to a URL?  Looks like this example runs some undefined function that presumably alters the color, instead of making a hyperlink.

Answer (score 3):

Add an anchor tag inside of the td and set its display attribute to block. This should make the entire td clickable.

```
#blue-border a{
    display: block;
}
```

or

```
<a href="link" style="display:block;">
```

Answer (score 2):

Define an OnClick event for the td:

```
<td id="blue-border" onclick="chooseStyle('blue-theme', 360)">...
```

Comment: What happens when you do this?

Comment: What would the syntax be for making the `<td>` hyperlink to a URL?

Answer (score 2):

If all you're doing is firing javascript, I'd suggest using `onclick` instead of an anchor tag in the first place, like:

```
<td id="cell123" onclick="chooseStyle('green-theme',360)">cell contents</td>
```

You can throw a simple css style on there if you want the mouse to become a pointer:

```
#cell123:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: How does `chooseStyle()` correspond to making the TD act as a clickable hyperlink to a URL?

Answer (score 2):

```
<table width="100%" class="blueCss">
    <tr>
        <td ID="tdBlue">
            <span id="Blue">Hello</span>
        </td>  
        <td>
            <span>other col</span>
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

css file:

```
.blueCss {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
    }

    .blueCss td {
        background-color: blue;
    }

    .blueCss:hover    {
        border-color: #00ae00;
    }

    .blueCss td:hover    {
        background-color: yellow;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tdLink = $('#tdBlue');

    tdLink.click(function(){
         alert('blue-theme');
    });
});
```

Check here: [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/NVKUr/)

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery with class
`$("tr td.data_col").click(function() {
       window.location = $(this).find('a').attr("href");
});`