# link_to block inside a each do loop not working

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb, link-to

I'm trying to render a table whose columns are subreddit titles and have links to each subreddit. However, this doesn't generate the link. I want to make the entire row a link, not a specific cell. What's the problem?

```
    <% @subreddits.each do |subreddit| %>
      <tr>
        <%= link_to subreddit do %>
          <td><%= something else %></td>
          <td><%= subreddit.title %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: You are wrapping the link _around_ the `<td>` element. Wrap the `<td>` around the link.

Comment: I want to make the entire cell a link. Updated the description to clarify that!

Comment: @alpaca HTML doesn't do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070232/how-to-make-a-cell-of-table-hyperlink

Answer (score 4):

You are wrapping the link *around* the `<td>` element. Wrap the `<td>` around the link.

```
<% @subreddits.each do |subreddit| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= link_to(subreddit.title, subreddit) %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

If you are wanting to make the *entire* `<td>` a link, you'll have to use the above code *plus* something like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6459846/2456549

---

**Update**

It looks like you updated your question to add additional `<td>`s. It looks like you are now wanting to make your `<tr>` a link. The best way to accomplish this is probably to just use JavaScript. See the link below for the solution. I would add CSS also so the `<tr>` has a pointed cursor, for improved UX.

[how to make a whole row in a table clickable as a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147821/how-to-make-a-whole-row-in-a-table-clickable-as-a-link)

---

I've went ahead and added the full solution here, without the need for dependencies like jQuery, granted, it is written in ES6, so change `const` to `var` if you need to. Please note, it hasn't been tested.

```
<tr class="cursor-pointer"
  data-behavior="clickable-row"
  data-url="<%= subreddit_url(subreddit) %>">
  <td><%= something else %></td>
  <td><%= subreddit.title %></td>
</tr>
```

---

```
const clickableRows = document.querySelectorAll('[data-behavior=clickable-row]');

clickableRows.addEventListener('click', event => {
  window.location = event.currentTarget.dataset.url;
});
```

---

```
.cursor-pointer { cursor: pointer; }
```