# How to align the text in a <td> which has been setup as a hyperlink

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, html-table

I'm using the solution described at

[How can I make a link from a <td> table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337914/how-to-make-a-td-a-link/3337975#3337975)

to make the td entries in my table hyperlinks. This is a nice and simple solution. But it's produces a side effect when I use display:block;. The hyperlink text is shifted upwards a little and is not centered. The image below shows the problem. If you look at the selected td "primary" you'll see it's too high.

[image: Table td vertical alignment issue]

Otherwise it's perfect as the highlighted td lines up with the blue th which is what I want.

How can I correct this?

The, simplified, code I'm using

```
----html----
<td>
    <div style="height:100%;width:100%;">
        <a href="my_url">
            primary
        </a>
    </div>
</td>

----css----
table {
background-color: White;
border: 10px solid Blue;
border-radius: 13px;
border-collapse: separate;
width: auto;
margin-top: 5px;
}

table th, td {
color: Black;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
border: 0;
padding: 0px;
}

table th {
color: White;
background: Blue;
}

table a {
color: Black;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 0px;
}

table a:hover {
color: White;
background: Blue;
}
```

Comment: `table td{text-align:center;}`

Comment: No such luck. I tried that but it seems to get ignored when display:block; is used. To be sure I set it on the td, a, and div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to center vertically your link could be the use of line-height. You can assign a fixed height to the td and the same amount of pixels to the "a" line-height

```
td{ height: 30px; }
td a{ line-height: 30px; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

Comment: Thank you. line-height solved the problem when set on both the th/td and a.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use line-height?

```
   table a {
      ...
      line-height: 1em; //or your row measure in pixels
   }
```

This behavior happens because you `display` the `a` **element** as a `block`, with the fixed size of the table cell (`heigh: 100%`), but the text inside the element have lines which have a default size (not affected by the size of the **element**).

Comment: gmast posted a little after this answer but I found that answer more useful. Setting 1em caused "primary" to move up a bit more. Setting 2em was nearly correct but it was slightly too low. First time I came across em as a unit. It sounds good but seems a little unusual. Not sure I fully got what it was doing in this situation.

Comment: That is why i commentes this `//or your row measure in pixels` but be my guest, if you have no more doubt, this is what matters (: