# php not "echoing" table row as a link that calls a javaScript function?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

So I am using php 5.6 for a project.
I am printing data from a mySQL database into a table:

```
echo "<tr>
        <a href='javascript:movieCookieCreator()'  id='".$row["dir"]."'>
            <td>".$row["name"]."</td>
        </a>
        <td>".$row["genre"]."</td>
      </tr>";
```

the id tag in the code above is used to store a directory for a movie, however, the row and its elements are not appearing as links.

This is the raw HTML as it is printed,

```
<center>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Genre</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <a href='javascript:movieCookieCreator()'  id='/movies/Shrek.mp4'>
        <td>Shrek</td>
    </a>
```

why is it not a link? and can the id tag be used to store data for javascript functions?

Comment: i think it is possible duplicate of [How can I make a link from a <td> table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337914/how-can-i-make-a-link-from-a-td-table-cell)

Comment: Your HTML structure is not valid. Put the `<a>` element **inside** the `<td>`

Comment: How exactly do you want the HTML to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML structure is not valid. If you want the entire table cell (`<td>`) to be clickable, try this instead...

```
?>
<tr>
    <td onclick="movieCookieCreator()" id="<?= htmlspecialchars($row['dir']) ?>"
        style="cursor:pointer">
        <?= htmlspecialchars($row['name']) ?>
    </td>
    <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['genre']) ?></td>
</tr>
```