# How do I embed a link onto background (mailchimp PHP)?

Tags: php, html, mailchimp

I have the following as my header:

```
<tr>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#3597D4" background="http://www.stampready.net/dashboard/editor/user_uploads/image_uploads/2017/08/15/jdKy8gpoibJTW1AX3Mf4vOLteaGmYZNSwksDrEuBhQR6CPq0zl92HVnI.jpg" style="background-size:cover;background-position:center;background-image:url(http://www.stampready.net/dashboard/editor/user_uploads/image_uploads/2017/08/15/jdKy8gpoibJTW1AX3Mf4vOLteaGmYZNSwksDrEuBhQR6CPq0zl92HVnI.jpg);">
    <br>
```

I want to add this link:

```
href="https://intechnica.com/insurance-bot-brokers-impact-non-human-traffic-nht-insurance-industry/?utm_source=mailchimp&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=2017_bot_control_insurance_2"
```

When I follow the usual procedure of adding  at the end, the image simply disappears.

EDIT ANSWERED (the  can't work without the background being a 'block' so I had to set the style to block): style="display: block; background

Comment: Is this to add a link as a background in **emails**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a link from a <td> table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337914/how-can-i-make-a-link-from-a-td-table-cell)

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, you can add a link with the `<a>` tag. To add a link to your background, just wrap it with this `<a>` tag like so :

```html
<tr>
  <a href="https://intechnica.com/insurance-bot-brokers-impact-non-human-traffic-nht-insurance-industry/?utm_source=mailchimp&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=2017_bot_control_insurance_2">
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#3597D4" background="http://www.stampready.net/dashboard/editor/user_uploads/image_uploads/2017/08/15/jdKy8gpoibJTW1AX3Mf4vOLteaGmYZNSwksDrEuBhQR6CPq0zl92HVnI.jpg" style="background-size:cover;background-position:center;background-image:url(http://www.stampready.net/dashboard/editor/user_uploads/image_uploads/2017/08/15/jdKy8gpoibJTW1AX3Mf4vOLteaGmYZNSwksDrEuBhQR6CPq0zl92HVnI.jpg);">
  </td>
  </a>
</tr>
```

Comment: If its for emails then the support for this will be very minimal.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed it was that but when I tried it, the image simply disappeared.

Comment: <tr>
    <a href="https://intechnica.com/business-transformation/" title="" target="_blank">
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#3597D4" background="http://www.stampready.net/dashboard/editor/user_uploads/image_uploads/2017/08/15/jdKy8gpoibJTW1AX3Mf4vOLteaGmYZNSwksDrEuBhQR6CPq0zl92HVnI.jpg" style="background-size:cover;background-position:center;background-image:url(http://www.stampready.net/dashboard/editor/user_uploads/image_uploads/2017/08/15/jdKy8gpoibJTW1AX3Mf4vOLteaGmYZNSwksDrEuBhQR6CPq0zl92HVnI.jpg);"></a> 

This is what I have. The image remains there but it is still not clickable.